# MutableDataLive not observing response from web service

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am using MVVM in my app with retrofit api calling. My code as below

```
MyViewModel :AndroidViewModel{
var response = MutableLiveData<String?>()

fun callapi(){
  response=MyRepo.instance().call(mobile.value.toString())
}
}



MyActivity:AppCompatActivity(){

 onCreate(b:Bumdle){
  myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(
        MyViewModel::class.java
    )
    
    activityBinding!!.lifecycleOwner = this
 myViewModel!!.response.observe(this) {
//here I am not getting response
}
```

}

//here my repo

```
Myrepo(){
fun call() : MutableLiveData<String?> {
    val config = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    myApi.getSystemConfig()?.enqueue(object : Callback<String?> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String?>, response: Response<String?>) {
            config.value = response.body()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String?>, t: Throwable) {

        }
    })
    return config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, You should update your `response` setting the value: **example** `response.value = MyRepo.instance().call(mobile.value.toString())`

Comment: I am returning MutableLiveData reference. please check in myrepo code